# I have a LEGO minifigure and I'm trying to determine the value of it

Tags: shopping, minifigures

I have a minifigure and I am trying to determine it's value - I'd like to know whether it's worth holding on to it for longer, or if I would get a reasonable price for it now.

Comment: Welcome to Bricks @Sarah1973, and glad to help! If you've found an answer helpful you can up-vote them and if it's answered your question sufficiently you can accept it with the tick ;)

Answer (score 5):

At the moment (12/09/2018) there are a few other people [offering that figure for sale on BrickLink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=gen023), varying from £110 to £230 (actual asking prices are in various currencies listed on the results page).

More importantly however, is the [Price Guide page](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogPG.asp?M=gen023&ColorID=0) - from there you can see that one figure apparently was bought this month for about £72, however in July one was purchased for around £108, while another was purchased for about £83.

From that, you could probably get a sale at around £100, but it might take a while to sell.

Comment: You are making a good point, the minifig seems to be very valuable now. However, this does not answer the OP's much more important question regarding the development of the price. I can imagine that the value of this particular minifig will not decrease because it will never be re-released. But this is speculation, therefore no answer, just a comment.

Comment: That is true, it's price is likely to increase due to increased rarity, but that will conversely reduce the number of people willing to pay the asking price...